# Swift set dynamic constraint

Tags: swift, layout

I have problem to set top anchor. I want to place content on center of the screen (it should look well on all iPhone models).
If possible do it with Storyboard, how...? Basically i thought i could get all size of view minus bottom block to place top block on center of the screen like on photo.
Or if impossible do this with storyboard, how to place it programmatically.
Something like this...

```
dataAndTimeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (view-100), constant: 18).isActive = true
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want that 6 labels in center of screen, right?

Comment: @ivarun yes, i can't set static constraint like 100 because on iPhone 8 looks good and on iPhone 5/SE looks horrible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will works for you.

1. Put all 6 labels inside UIView.
2. Give that View’s Equal width, leading and trailing with it’s parent
   view(that while view).
3. Give height that you want.
4. Give Horizontal and Vertical centre constraint to this view to Your
   Main View.

Comment: if i put static constraint like you said on iPhone 8/X, it will still looks good on older iPhone models?

Comment: Yes, you should try once.

Comment: Omit step 3, since the UILabels have intristic content size which means the height will/should be dynamic.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, can skip step 3.